# How to connect phone headphones as laptop headphones?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

is it possible to use my phone's wired headphones (which have only one output jack) to my laptop and use it as both earphones and mic? Which normally require 2 separate jacks

Comment: I assume your phone's headphones has a mic piece?

Comment: Yes, they do. Problem is the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it may be possible but with out knowing the headphone it's hard to tell.

Assuming your headphone is both a mic and speakers, and the other end is using either a jack or a mini-jack, you'll need to see how many black lines are around the connector. 1, 2 or 3. In music, 1 means mono and 2 stereo. The third is for 'other', in this instance most likely a microphone.

This image may help (although not your device)

[image]

**EDIT**

As per our comments and keep all relevant data in the main answer, you will need a splitter or adapter - please see http://www.meelec.com/MEElectronics_Skype_Adapter_for_PC_p/adptr-skype-22in-35.htm for an example. If this link fails, then try a search engine for a term similar to "trrs adapter" or "trrs skype adapter".

Answer (score 0):

You might need an adapter like one of [these](http://www.theheadsetbuddy.com/phone-headset-to-pc/), which can convert a TRRS type headset to two separate audio and microphone plugs.